# Rails: Joining tables and grouping by count

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm new to Rails and currently working on a tagging system where I can assign multiple tags to events and the same tag to multiple events.

The Tag model looks like this:

```
has_many :taggings,
has_many :events, through: :taggings
```

The Event model looks like this:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :taggings
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```

I have three tables like this:

```
TAGS
id | name (string)

EVENTS
id | name (string)

TAGGINGS
id | tag_id | event_id
```

Now I'm trying to fetch the top 10 most used tags. I essentially need to join taggings and tags tables together and group by tag_id in taggings. Something like this:

```
Tagging.group('tag_id').order('count_id DESC').limit(10).count('id')
```

But, with a join on tags so that I can grab the name field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Tag.select('tags.*, COUNT(taggings.id) AS tagging_count').
    joins(:taggings).group('tags.id').
    order('tagging_count DESC').
    limit(10).pluck(:name)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to modify this slightly to:
    Tag.select('tags.*, COUNT(taggings.id) AS tagging_count').
        joins(:taggings).group('tags.id').
        order('tagging_count DESC').
        limit(10).
        collect(&:name)

Comment: @FrankGordon : You can do anything at the place of `pluck(:name)`, like: `collect(&:name)`, `map(&:name)`, or `map{|t| t.name }`. `pluck` was just an example to show how you can fetch `name` attribute. I am glad that I could help.